# How to validate checkbox in a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am creating a seat reservation system. In my system, the code check number of seats a bus contains then pass it inside a **for loop**. When a user pick **2 passengers**, it means two seats will be booked. How can I validate the checkbox in the **for loop** depending on the number of passenger(s) selected.

Using the GUI for more explanation.

[image]
on the main page, 2 there indicates number of passenger(s) selected.

[image]

When you come to the second page where the values are passed to, you can see **2 Adults** as the selected number of passengers. When you click on **Submit Button** it does not validate the checkbox based on the number of passenger(s) selected. And if I should put **required** in the checkbox it validates the whole checkbox since it is in a **loop**

`$_SESSION['seat_no']` is the number of seat(s) a bus contains. Let assume a user that want to book a seat selected **two passengers** which means two seats is booked, how can I validate the checkbox based on the number of seat(s) selected?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['seat_no']; $i++) {

        if(in_array($i,$mseat)){
            echo "<div class='checkbox_wrapper_pick'>        
                    <label>".$i."</label>
                </div>";
        }else{

            echo "<div class='checkbox_wrapper'>
                    <input type='checkbox' value=".$i." name='seat_book[]' />
                    <label>".$i."</label>
                  </div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

**The full source code:**

```
<?php include("header.php"); error_reporting(0); ?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$date = $_POST['d_date'];
$nop = $_POST['nop'];

$_SESSION['from'] = $from;
$_SESSION['to'] = $to;
$_SESSION['date'] = $date;
$_SESSION['nop'] = $nop;

$get = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM routes WHERE present_loc = '$from' and destination = '$to' ");
while($roys = mysqli_fetch_array($get)){
//get bus details
$bno = $roys['bus_no'];
$ploc = $roys['present_loc'];
$des = $roys['destination'];
$time = $roys['dept_time'];
$_SESSION['time'] = $time;
$amt = $roys['amount'];
$_SESSION['amt'] = $amt;


$b = str_replace( ',', '',$_SESSION['amt'] );

if( is_numeric($b) ) {
    $a = $b;
}

$bus = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from bus where bus_no = '$bno'");
while($bu = mysqli_fetch_array($bus)){
  $_SESSION['model'] = $bu['model'];
  $_SESSION['seat_no'] = $bu['seat_no'];
  $_SESSION['ac'] = $bu['bus_type'];
  $_SESSION['excess_luggage'] = $bu['excess_luggage'];
  $_SESSION['more_legs'] = $bu['more_legs'];
  $_SESSION['id'] = $bu['id'];
}


$coun = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select count(booking_id) as seat, seats from booking where bus_no = '$bno' and seats !='' GROUP by booking_id" );
$mseat = array();
while($e = mysqli_fetch_array($coun)){
$bseat = $e['seat'];
$mseat[] = $e['seats'];
}
//$seatss = array();


$seat_string = implode(",",$mseat);

//get seats
$couns = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select sum(counter) as seat from booking where bus_no = '$bno' and seats !='' GROUP by bus_no" );
$rseats = mysqli_fetch_array($couns);
$lseat = $rseats['seat'];
if($_SESSION['seat_no'] == $lseat){
  $tell = " No more seat(s) available.";
}else{
  $tell = $_SESSION['seat_no'] - $lseat. "  Seat(s) remaining.";
}

}


}

?>
   <!--Main layout-->
   <main class="mt-5">
  <!--Main container-->

  <form  action="details" method="POST"> 
    <!--Grid row-->
    <div class="row">



    <div class="col-lg-12 title-header mb-3 mx-auto  z-depth-1">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8">
<?php echo '<h2> '.$_SESSION['from']. ' to '. $_SESSION['to']. '</h2>'; ?><br/>
<b><?php echo $_SESSION['date']; ?> ::  <?php if($_SESSION['nop'] < '2') { echo $_SESSION['nop'] . ' Adult'; }
elseif($_SESSION['nop'] > 1) { echo $_SESSION['nop'] . ' Adults'; }
?></b>
</div>

</div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-lg-12 mbody"> <label style="margin-left: 4%; font-weight:bolder; font-size:20px; color:#000;">Details </label> </div>


  <div class="col-lg-12 mbody bg-white ">   

 <table class="table  table_view" style = "width: 100%; margin-left: 4%; margin-right:4%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><b><?php echo  $_SESSION['model'];  ?></b><br/><?php echo  $_SESSION['from']. ' to '. $_SESSION['to'];  ?>
<br/><?php if($_SESSION['ac'] == 'AC') { echo '<span class="alert-info ac">'. $_SESSION['ac'] .'</span>'; }
else{ echo '<span class="alert-warning">No AC</pan>'; } ?>
<?php if($_SESSION['more_legs'] == 'Yes') { echo '<span class="alert-info ac">More Leg Room</span>'; }
else{ echo '<span class="alert-warning no">More Leg Not Available</pan>'; } ?>
</td>
<td><b>Departing Time</b><br/><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo  $_SESSION['time'];  ?></td>
<td> <img id = "seatimg" src="../images/seatsLayout/av.gif" class="img-responsive"> <?php echo $tell; ?></td>

<td>Adult  <b>₦<?php echo $_SESSION['amt']; ?></b></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
   </table>

 </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="col-lg-12 mbody"> <label style="margin-left: 3%; font-weight:bolder; font-size:20px; color:#000;"><img id = "seatimg" src="../images/seatsLayout/av.gif" class="img-responsive"> Select Seat</label> </div>
<div class="row detail">
    <!--Grid column-->
 <div class="col-lg-7 animation slideUp" >

 <div class="well" id="bus_seats_layout" >
                    <table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing = "1" id="seatstable">

                        <tr>
                                <td><img id = "driverimg" src="../images/seatsLayout/steering.png" class="img-responsive" width="25" height="25"></td>

                <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
                <?php
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['seat_no']; $i++) {

                  if(in_array($i,$mseat)){
                  echo "
                  <div class='checkbox_wrapper_pick'>

              <label>".$i."</label>
              </div>
                  ";
                }else{

                  echo "
                  <div class='checkbox_wrapper'>
                <input type='checkbox' value=".$i." name='seat_book[]' />
              <label>".$i."</label>
              </div>
                  ";
                }


                }

                ?>
                </td>

                        </tr>



                    </table>
            </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-5">
<ul class="bt">
<li><img src="../images/seatsLayout/seat_available.png" class="img-responsive"> Available</li>
<li><img src="../images/seatsLayout/picked.png" class="img-responsive"> Selected</li>
<li><img src="../images/seatsLayout/seat_booked.png" class="img-responsive"> Booked</li>
</ul>
</div>



</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">

<input type="hidden" name="bus_no" value="<?php echo $bno; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="to" value="<?php echo $to; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="from" value="<?php echo $from; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amt" value="<?php echo $nop*$a; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="nop" value="<?php echo $nop; ?>">

<div class="form-group">


<div align="right">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="bme" value="Continue">
</div>
  </div>

</div>

</div>



</div>
</form>
</main>

  <?php include("footer.php");  ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to validate the checkbox in a form after user selects it or show checkboxes based on your store value in $_SESSION['seat_no'] ?

Comment: And what is `$mseat`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Yes, when the user select the number of seat(s) is should validate it on submit.

Comment: But this is not the Submit code. This is the code that creates the output to the screen for the user to select from...Right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, $mseat is the number of seats already booked. This is fetched from the database.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Yes, it is the code  that creates the output to the screen for the user to select from

Comment: SO what validation are you talking about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183413/discussion-between-wealth-ouseinfo-and-riggsfolly).